# How to write classes with parameter in scss?

Tags: css, class, parameters, colors, sass

Is it possible to write a class with predefined color-HexCodes?
So that in my HTML I can create elements like:

```
$yellow: #FFFF00;

.color($colorName) { 
    color: $colorName; 
}

<div class="color(yellow)">
</div>
```

This would be my problems solution. My problem is that I have too much classes with different colors in my .scss file.

Thanks

Comment: This is not what Sass has been created for. Why don't you use inline CSS instead? `color: yellow` seems the best way to go with (in this particular case).

Comment: You understand that Sass is only ever compiled straight to CSS, right?  It never gets sent to the client.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can achieve this in SCSS fairly easily. For the quick solution: [here's the code in a JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwhmpt12/1/).

**The more elaborate explanation:**

Since [SASS 3.3](http://thesassway.com/news/sass-3-3-released) you can use the [map data structure](http://thesassway.com/news/sass-3-3-released#maps). They store a mix of key/value pairs:

```
$map: (key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3);
```

So, in your case, you could create a map of colors (as long or as short as you like) for later reference:

```
$colors: (
    red: #ff0000,
    yellow: #ffd000,
    blue: #00baff,
    green: #00ff00
);
```

Now, to generate the CSS classes you need to loop over the map with a nice bit of SASS:

```
@each $colorname, $color in $colors {
    .square--#{$colorname} {
       background-color: $color;
    }
}
```

All this `@each` loop does is cycle over each key/value pair in $colors, assigning the key *(e.g: red)* to $colorname and the value *(e.g: #ff0000)* to $color.

The compiled CSS would be:

```
.square--red    { background-color: #ff0000; }
.square--yellow { background-color: #ffd000; }
.square--blue   { background-color: #00baff; }
.square--green  { background-color: #00ff00; }
```

If in the future you want to add a new color it's as simple as adding a key/value pair to the $colors map and compiling!

Comment: That's a nice answer (and it's been done to death on hundreds of other questions), but that's not what the OP is asking for.  They specifically state "My problem is that i got too much classes with colors in my scss-file."

Comment: I'm aware that the OP was asking for something slightly different. But since what he is seeking is not possible, it makes sense to point him in the direction of the closest feasible work-around. In fact, the example CSS he supplies isn't far off the method I suggest – he's after a function which will generate the CSS styles for him. Whether or not my answer suits his needs is up to him.